# failed upgrade to windows 7--keeps trying to rollback but doesn't

Tags: windows-7

My husband tried to upgrade from vista 64 bit to windows 7 64 bit on an HP pavilion dv4-1275mx.  He's getting a screen that says upgrade not successful.  Your previous version is being restored.  Except it isn't.  It just keeps trying to reboot over and over.  I tried the system restore disc I made when we bought it and it says something about system restore won't work while the computer is in a limited state or something.  Anyway, it didn't work.  What should I do now.  I don't have a vista cd--it came installed.w

Answer (score 1):

I believe i heared some problems with upgrading 64 bit.

The only thing what i could say is the following;

-Download GParted: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php

-Burn it to a disc/USB etc...

-Boot from it

-Make a new partition (if it's possible) at least 16 GB.

-Or you could just use an external harddrive

-Put a clean Windows 7 install on the new partition/hard drive

-copy important files to that new win7 installation

-delete the 1st partition using the disc

I would say that is a method.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is a special partition with an image of a fresh OS inside the BIOS.

Perhaps it is called something like recovery boot or similar.